# How to push Fossil local repository to remote hosting

Tags: repository, push, fossil

It would be great if you could help me with one thing.

I'm using Fossil as my version manager. Using this on my PC is not a problem but when I try to push it to remote repository I can't.

Here's the thing:

When inside folder with my repository I type

```
fossil push https://chiselapp.com/user/sebatbg/repository/nres
```

I get info that:
Error: Wrong project

When I type

```
fossil push https://sebatbg@chiselapp.com/user/sebatbg/repository/nres
```

It asks for my password but when I enter it fossil says that Login failed
I tried both my pass to chisel app and for specific repository but result is the same.

Could anyone tell me step by step how to do the push?

Thank you

Comment: When you create a new repo on ChiselApp, there is an option `Override project code (Optional, but may be needed if pushing an already created repo to Chisel.): ` and there you can give the project code of your local repo, which you can get with the `fossil info` command.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I had cloned a remote repository, but could not push to it.
I could solve it by adding the username to the remote url

remote-url https://{username}@chiselapp.com/user/{chiselab-user}/repository/{repository-name}

you are then prompted for the password of the remote repository.

Answer (score 2):

Fossil assigns a unique ID, called the "project ID", to each new repository. The error message "Wrong project" means that you've got different repositories locally and remotely, that their project-IDs don't match.

The only way I know to publish an existing local repository on Chisel is to upload said repository, and then set the `remote-url` of your local repository to the Chisel URL, either explicitly or by pulling from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing local repository that you would like to upload to the chiselapp hosting service, the process can be a bit awkward. If your repository is smaller than 8M, chiselapp provides a command `Upload repository` that may suit your purposes. Otherwise, this is what you need to do:

1. Navigate to a source tree for the local repository.
2. Issue the `fossil info` command and copy the `project-code` of the local
   repository. This is a SHA1 hash.
3. Log in to `chiselapp.com` website and click on the `Create Repository`
   link in the header of the home page.
4. Paste the previously copied `project-code` into the *Override Project Code*
   field of the resulting form.
5. Fill the remaining fields as appropriate and click the `Create Repository`
   button at the bottom of the page.
6. Record the password that is then assigned to you.
7. Navigate to the `chiselapp` dashboard and click on the name of the newly
   created repository. This should bring you to the fossil web interface of this repository.
8. Login to the new repository using your local username and the recorded 
   password. This should be the only user so far and should have setup user permissions.
9. Navigate to the Admin/Stats page and check that the **Project ID** of the new 
   remote repository matches the `project-code` of the local repository.
10. Back in the local repository's source tree issue the command

    ```
    fossil push https://<username>:<recorded-password>@chiselapp.com/user/<username>/repository/<repository-name> -R <local-repository-file>
    ```